# Could not find method flutter()

Tags: android, flutter, macos, dart

I am trying to open my app in android emulator on macos but I'm getting following error

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/home/app_sources/my_app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 63

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method flutter() for arguments [build_enl1wb3rxbgojqnsmrkb1pqib$_run_closure3@4a124cf3] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Also if I try to `Open Android module in Android Studio`

[image: ONE]

When it opens there is no configuration

[image: two]

When I try to add configuration there is no module to select

[image: three]

I've been facing this issue for past 3 days and trust me I've tried every topic on this website, every article on this matter nothing worked, so please don't suggest google search because I've done that a lot!

Note:

1. Using `Sync Project with Gradle Files` return same error as above
2. Using `Invalidate Caches` doesn't help either.
3. Comment `include ':app'` in `settings.gradle` and sync, again uncomment and sync doesn't help either.

**Any idea?**

## UPDATE

`settings.gradle`

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

`android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`android/app/build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: hey can you share your  `setting.gradle` and `build.gradle` file both app level and project level.?

Comment: have added firebase in this project?

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

> I've removed `Flutter SDK` and `Dart SDK` from my system and
> re-install them then error gone away.

*PS:* I have no idea why this happened or why clean install solved the problem (specially that my installed version was the same version as this clean install) but it did the trick, that's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the build.gradle from

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
```

to

```
def localPropertiesFile = new rootProject.file('local.properties')
```

Will solve u r problem.

Comment: thanks, will try it and let you know

Comment: also try to replace this line with `new` keyword in `setting.gradle` file like this `def flutterSdkPath = new properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")`

Comment: it says `startup failed:
  build file '/Users/home/app_sources/my_app/android/app/build.gradle': 2: unable to resolve class rootProject.file` and `build file '/Users/home/app_sources/my_app/android/app/build.gradle': 9: unable to resolve class localProperties.getProperty `

Answer (score 0):

I removed thie new and everything is fine

android/app/build.gradle

throw **new** GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32795119)